The 'true' condition isn't working with the nodes slots withing the IBM Waston Assistant
I’m attempting to build a chatbot using IBM Watson Assistant (non-coding).
I’m following instructions I’ve built a node that allows the user to retrieve information about a specific city and and it’s address. I’m must also bring up a generic response to a prompt that doesn’t specify a city inputted in the node. However I cannot get the chatbot to correctly respond with a generic answer to an unknown city ( a city not inputted into the node). The “true”condition, which is in the last slot, should return the response
True => Our locations are listed on our Locations page.
Trust me when I tell you I’ve followed the instructions to the letter.
If anyone knows of a solution, I’ll be eternally grateful.
I've included screenshots.[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/GsS6c59Q.png)
If you look at the screenshots of the node and the chatbot response, you'll see my problem. The 'true' condition isn't respond to the prompt.
